# Git undo merge and add for a single file

Tags: git

Having merged a branch I got some merge conflicts.

I fixed them and for every file I fixed I added it with `git add` to the merge commit.

How could I undo a `git add` of one of these files if I realized later by running the code the merge is wrong? all this **before** commiting anything, the files are still added and modified and uncommited.

Comment: Just fix the work-tree version and re-do the `git add`. The merge is not finished until you run `git commit` (or, if your Git is new enough, `git merge --continue`, which simply runs `git commit` anyway).

Comment: But I would like to have again the conflict in that file, to reset it somehow, to have <<<<<<< and >>>>>

Comment: Ah! That was not clear, but see the two (as of now) answers below; both are correct.  `-m` or `--conflict=<style>` should both do the trick. The `--conflict` variety allows you to choose between `merge` style and `diff3` style; `-m` uses whichever of these two you set in your configuration. I like the `diff3` style myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would like to have again the conflict in that file, to reset it somehow, to have `<<<<<<<` and `>>>>>`

You can [restore the merge conflict markers](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#_checking_out_conflicts) in your working directory by using the [`--conflict`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout---conflictltstylegt) option of [`git-checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

```
git checkout --conflict=merge -- path/to/file
```

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#_checking_out_conflicts):

> This will re-checkout the file again and replace the merge conflict markers. This can be useful if you want to reset the markers and try to resolve them again.

Answer (score 3):

**If you want to undo git add**

With `git add` you have staged a file. You can use git reset with the path to file in order to unstage that particular file.

```
git reset <filePath>
```

From the official [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset):

> This means that git reset  is the opposite of git add

**If you want to correct your merge**

Since you have not committed the merged file, you can still make changes to it (assuming you know which changes need to be made). You can then continue with adding and committing the file as usual.

**Edit** : Adding the [correct answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50923951/1695393) for completeness of this answer.

If you would like to "undo" the *merge* after you have applied it and before you have committed it, you can use the `-m` flag on `git checkout`

```
git checkout -m <file>
```

Comment: With git reset will the file be in the conflict merge state? with the separators <<<<< and >>>> etc

Comment: that git reset won't be able to do. For that you can try: `git checkout -m <FILE>`